# MySql - Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables in MySql but I keep running into the following error:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'list.user_id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT list.title
FROM list
INNER JOIN user
ON list.user_id=user.id
```

The table 'list' does contain a FK to the user table called 'user_id'.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Is weird. Are you sure that you have that column and reference?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this. It's really strange.

Comment: Are you sure user_id belongs to the list table and id belongs to user? - maybe user_id is in user and id in list? weird small errors like this happen all the time

Comment: Do you connect to the correct database?

Comment: @ypercube AH! The dev machine is pointing to another db.. doh.. that's embarrassing :)

Comment: Happens... lol.. good you caught it

Answer (score 1):

seems you have given wrong table name or column. please check if you have `user` table and `user_id` column in it.

Comment: Do you mean list table with user_id column? Yes. I'm sure it's there

Comment: check if it is lists or list. if ok then try to  run simple query select user_id from list